# Unable to split a string into a new line

Tags: javascript, html

There is so much documentation and I've looked at dozens of articles. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but essentially what I am trying to do is show text in a span with multi lines:

Span:

```
 <span style="color:red" id="errors"></span>


 var errText = "<b>NOTE:</b>  There are " + "<b>" + errors.length + "</b>" + “ issues that must be addressed. Please make changes as necessary.";
```

Goal is to make this text look like this:

```
 NOTE: There are 3 issues that must be addressed.
 Please make changes as necessary.
```

I've trying using , I've tried \n but nothing seems to work.

Ex 1:

```
var errText ="<b>NOTE:</b>  There are " + "<b>" + errors.length + "</b>" + “ issues that must be addressed.\n Please make changes as necessary.";
```

Ex 2:

```
var errText ="<b>NOTE:</b>  There are " + "<b>" + errors.length + "</b>" + “ issues that must be addressed.\ 
 Please make changes as necessary.";
```

WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `<br>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<span>NOTE: There are 3 issues that must be addressed. <br> Please make changes as necessary</span>
```